# User Profile Wizard

Tags: windows, администрирование

Домен,вход по eToken. На компьютере есть настроенный профиль "Вася",настройки которого нужно перенести на вновь созданный "Петя".Использую User Profile Wizard.Получается,что он "подвязывает" профиль "Петя" к "Вася", при этом вся информация созданная у "Пети" теперь храниться в папке C:\Users\Вася. К примеру Петя удаляет файл в расшаренной папке на сервере. Зайдя на сервер я не могу понять,что это сделал он т.к. имя отображается Вася. Как грамотно перенести профиль пользователя?